# How to register service in IP address not container Id in docker for spring-cloud service?

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have tried to set eureka.instance.hostname、preferIpAddress、ipAddress、instanceId，but the instance id is still docker container id.  How do I set them to IP address?

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${server.host}
    preferIpAddress: true
    ipAddress: ${server.host}
    instanceId: ${server.host}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: 
        http://pitbull:j1n3v9z9j3nc@${server.remote}:8888/eureka/
```

[image: screenshot01]

Answer (score 3):

By default, the container hostname is the container id. You can override this with the `--hostname` flag in the `docker run` command.

I don't think that is the root of your issue though..

It sounds like what you really want is to set your service config to bind to the container's localhost address and then either:

- run the docker image with `docker run --net=host ...` (binding the container directly to your host network interface / IP)
- run the docker image with `docker run --net=bridge -p 8888:8888` (`--net=bridge` is the default run mode and does not need to be specified.) The `-p 8888:8888` will forward the port from your host IP to the docker container runtime.